# Configure SSRS to build reports using asp.net core app

Tags: ssrs

I try to build the simplest report with SSRS via asp.net core application.

The asp.net core application has windows authentication, and I would like that any domain identified user could generate a report.

I downloaded the latest to day SSRS version (SQL Server 2019 Reporting Services), installed it but then lost in configuration.

('PP-09...' is the machine name taken by default by the SSRS wizard):

[image]

then, here I am not sure what account should I use, I let by default, but probably I should use the MyDomain\MyUser as in Windows?

[image]

here, I don't know what account to put, I let as is the default built-in.

It ask me for encryption key backup... I am new in this, don't really understand what for, I created a new folder and saved there an encryption key, provided a strong password, and then it completed the task:

[image]
[image]
[image]

however, when I try to access the /reportServer page I see

[image]

also acceeding `http://localhost/reports/` does not really work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could unblock this by using "Network Service" as "Service Account"
[image]
and (supposing `http://localhost:80/Reports` is your SSRS Web Portal URL)
[image]

- open Internet Explorer *as administrator*;
- open `http://localhost/Reports/manage/catalogitem/security/`
- added current user "DOMAIN\MyUser" as Content Manager.
  [image]

Now I was able to open the default browser in normal mode:

[image]